# discord.py cog not functioning how it should

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So I've been trying to figure out this issue for a few days now but I'm trying to get the this cog to function correctly, example how it functions:

If 4 members join within 30 seconds the cog will notify mods that there is a possible server raid.

Previously I got this error:

`File "C:\Users\User\Documents\stream\cogs\spamdetect.py", line 19, in on_member_join
    last_reset = datetime.strptime(self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None`

originally the code I'm working with looked like this

```js
async def on_member_join(self, member):
      server = member.server
      last_reset = datetime.strptime(self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
      reset_time = (datetime.now() - last_reset).total_seconds()
      if reset_time > 30:
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
        self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
      if self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] < self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]:
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] += 1
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
        return
      if (self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] >= self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]) and reset_time <= 30:
        channel_id = self.settings[server.id]["channel"]
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await self.bot.send_message(channel, content=":warning: @Mods There is a possible raid happening! To lock down channels use the command `!lock` :warning:")
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
        self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
        return
```

Then I added a check around where the error was in the code

```js
 async def on_member_join(self, member):    
        server = member.server
        if self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] is None:
            reset_time = 999 # a big number to trigger the timeout now
        else:
            last_reset = datetime.strptime(self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            reset_time = (datetime.now() - last_reset).total_seconds()
            if reset_time > 30:
                self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
                self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
                dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
            if self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] < self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]:
                self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] += 1
                dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
            return
            if (self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] >= self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]) and reset_time <= 30:
                channel_id = self.settings[server.id]["channel"]
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            await self.bot.send_message(channel, content=":warning: @mods There is a possible raid happening! :warning:")
            self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
            self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
            dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
            return
```

There is now no error, however the cog is now not functioning how it should when tested it won't send the `await self.bot.send_message(channel, content=":warning: @mods There is a possible raid happening! :warning:")` on line 35.

Here is the full code I'm working with

```js
import asyncio
import os
import discord
from datetime import datetime
from __main__ import send_cmd_help, settings
from discord.ext import commands
from .utils import checks
from .utils.dataIO import dataIO

class AntiRaid():
    """Alerts Staff about possible incoming raids"""

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.settings = dataIO.load_json("data/anti_raid/settings.json")

    async def on_member_join(self, member):    
        server = member.server
        if self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] is None:
            reset_time = 999 # a big number to trigger the timeout now
        else:
            last_reset = datetime.strptime(self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
            reset_time = (datetime.now() - last_reset).total_seconds()
            if reset_time > 30:
                self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
                self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
                dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
            if self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] < self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]:
                self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] += 1
                dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
            return
            if (self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] >= self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"]) and reset_time <= 30:
                channel_id = self.settings[server.id]["channel"]
                channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
            await self.bot.send_message(channel, content=":warning: @mods There is a possible raid happening! :warning:")
            self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
            self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
            dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
            return

    @commands.group(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    @checks.admin_or_permissions(manage_server=True)
    async def antiraid(self, ctx):
        """Settings for AntiRaid"""
        if ctx.invoked_subcommand is None:
            await self.bot.send_cmd_help(ctx)

    @antiraid.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def channel(self, ctx, channel: discord.Channel):
        """Sets channel the bot should send alerts to"""
        server = ctx.message.server
        if server.id not in self.settings:
            self.settings[server.id] = {}
        if "channel" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["channel"] = {}
        if channel.id not in self.settings[server.id]["channel"]:
            self.settings[server.id]["channel"] = None
        if "join_count" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = None
        if "max_joins" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"] = 4
        if "time_since_last_reset" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = None
        if "active" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["active"] = False

        self.settings[server.id]["channel"] = channel.id
        self.settings[server.id]["join_count"] = 0
        dataIO.save_json("data/anti_raid/settings.json", self.settings)
        await self.bot.say("New active AntiRaid channel set to {}!".format(channel.mention))

    @antiraid.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def max(self, ctx, max_joins: int):
        """Sets # of joins before bot alerts staff (default is 4)"""
        server = ctx.message.server
        if server.id not in self.settings:
            self.settings[server.id] = {}
        if "max_joins" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"] = None
        self.settings[server.id]["max_joins"] = max_joins
        dataIO.save_json("data/anti_raid/settings.json", self.settings)
        await self.bot.say("AntiRaid maximum number of joins per 30 seconds is now {}!".format(max_joins))
        
    @antiraid.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
    async def active(self, ctx, active: str):
        """Sets whether AntiRaid is active and turned on
        Options for active are true or false"""
        server = ctx.message.server
        active_state = None

      # Error handling
        if server.id not in self.settings:
            await self.bot.say("You must set a channel before activating!")
            return
        if "channel" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            await self.bot.say("You must set a channel before activating!")
            return
        if active.lower() != "true" and active.lower() != "false":
            await self.bot.say("Invalid option entered!")
            return
        else:
            if active.lower() == "true":
                active_state = True
                state = "ON"
            else:
                active_state = False
                state = "OFF"
        if "active" not in self.settings[server.id]:
            self.settings[server.id]["active"] = {}
        self.settings[server.id]["active"] = active_state
        self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"] = str(datetime.now())
        dataIO.save_json("data/lockdown/settings.json", self.settings)
        channel_id = self.settings[server.id]["channel"]
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(channel_id)
        await self.bot.say("Active setting has been applied and is now {} for channel {}!".format(state, channel.mention))

def check_folder():
    if not os.path.isdir("data/anti_raid"):
        os.mkdir("data/anti_raid")

def check_file():
    if not dataIO.is_valid_json("data/anti_raid/settings.json"):
        dataIO.save_json("data/anti_raid/settings.json", {})

def setup(bot):
    check_folder()
    check_file()
    bot.add_cog(AntiRaid(bot))
```

If anyone can help me where I'm going wrong here, first I thought it could be the timeout issue but it seems I might be incorrectly placing code.

Comment: It looks like you unindented a `return` about halfway through the `else` block.  That will stop the second half of that block from running

Comment: thanks Ive just fixed this but it doesn't seem to have corrected the issue.

Comment: if `self.settings[server.id]["time_since_last_reset"]` is `None`, your coroutine sets the local variable `reset_time` to `999` and then exits.  That's probably not what you want.  I'm having some trouble following what your program is supposed to do, so here's how I would do it: your dictionary maps server ids to [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)s of time stamps, with `maxlen` equal to `4`.  Whenever a `Member` joins, you push the current timestamp onto the deque, and then check if all of them are within the last 30 seconds.